# ASP.NET Gridview Append value to Edit Template Control before Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that supports updating records.
I have an edit template with a Dropdownlist(ddl) that replaces textbox.
The DDL is bound to a datasource and I need to append a value (the current value of this field to the DDL). This enables users to select the current value as well as alternate values from the DDL.

The issue is that I need the DDl to be bound ('<%# Bind("Element") %>') so the update function works but I need to bind it after the current value of the field has been appended to the DDL which now occurs during the RowDataBound event.

In a nutshell; I need to get the current value of a field appended to the DDL before the Bind so my update works (else I get a DDL does not contain vale error). What is the earliest point/event where I can retrieve the value of a field (after the edit button is clicked) in a gridview so I can do some plumbing before the Binding takes place?

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question!  You could handle the [`RowEditing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowediting.aspx) event, which gets fired as the row is going into "Edit Mode" (when the Edit Button is clicked).  Then just use the [`NewEditIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewediteventargs.neweditindex.aspx) property to find the row you're about to Edit.

So, something like this in your Code Behind:

```
protected void myGridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    // the row you're editing
    int rowToEdit = e.NewEditIndex; 

    // The numeric ordinal of your column where your DropDownList is.  I just picked 5 at random
    int ddlColumnIndex = 5; 

    // Get the DropDownList you're interested in modifying
    DropDownList myDDL = (DropDownList)myGridView.Rows[rowToEdit].Cells[ddlColumnIndex].FindControl("myDDL");

    // Do whatever processing you need to do here
}
```

Comment: @User937036: Glad I could help =) Feel free to click the empty "check mark" next to this answer to indicate that it worked for you.You can see how that works here: [Accept An Answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)